# How can I access an outside attribute from within a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I have designed a GUI with PyQt5 Designer.

I want the **tryingMethod** to always be checking for incoming messages from the server, so I made a thread so that the GUI and the run method can run simountaneously, which works.

The issue is that when I try to access variable "Button" from Ui_Form, it throws the following error: AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'Button'.

I have tried passing self to the thread as an argument to the tryingMethod thread but it gives me "Unexpected type(s): (() -> None, Ui_Form) Warning"

I have tried creating several different classes but I am not able to resolve the issue. Any help is appreciated! :)

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.tryingMethod)
        t.start()




    def tryingMethod(self):
        self.Button.setText("TESTING")  ##This doesn't work.

        while True:
            message = self.clientSocket.receive()



    def setupUi(self, Form):
        //Code has been shortened
        self.Button.setFont(font)
        self.Button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.Button.setObjectName("Button")



if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     ui = Ui_Form()
     ui.setupUi(Form)
     Form.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt does not allow the GUI to be updated from another thread directly, a possible solution is to use signals but for this we need a class that inherits `QObject`, on the other hand it is not recommended to modify the class generated by Qt Designer, that class only serves to fill in the widget So you could take advantage of creating a class that inherits from the widget, and since it is a widget also inherits from `QObject`, in that class we will create a signal, and connect that signal to the `setText()` method of the button.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        # Code has been shortened
        self.Button.setFont(font)
        self.Button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.Button.setObjectName("Button")

class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    someSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.tryingMethod)
        self.someSignal.connect(self.Button.setText)
        t.start()

    def tryingMethod(self):
        self.someSignal.emit("TESTING")  ##This doesn't work.
        while True:
            message = self.clientSocket.receive()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     w = Form()
     w.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating `ui = Ui_Form()` before you call `ui.setupUi(Form)`.

`ui = Ui_Form()` will next call the `__init__` method, which in turn starts creates and starts your thread. This will (in the worst case) attempt to set the button before it's even created, which is likely why you're getting the error.

You need to create the button before you attempt to use it. One option would be to move the thread creation outside of `__init__`, like this:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def startThread(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.tryingMethod)
        t.start()

    def tryingMethod(self):
        self.Button.setText("TESTING")  ##This doesn't work.
        while True:
            message = self.clientSocket.receive()

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        # Code has been shortened
        self.Button.setFont(font)
        self.Button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.Button.setObjectName("Button")


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     ui = Ui_Form()
     ui.setupUi(Form)
     Form.show()

     # call after creation
     ui.startThread()

     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That said, your code has some other mistakes such as eyllanesc mentioned.